# remove d3 annotation after transition

Tags: d3.js

I have some annotations that are only meant for certain `year` slides. For example

```
        const makeAnnotations = d3.annotation().annotations(annotations)
        if (year == 2009)
            {svg.append("g").call(makeAnnotations)}
        else {CODE_GOES_HERE}
```

On any `year` other than 2009, if there is annotation, I'd like to remove it. How can I express this in d3?

Answer (score 0):

It seen the annotation is implemented by d3-annotation library. However, I recommend you add a unique id on the `g` element you append. It is helpful for further handling and styling.

Back the question. If you have only one annotation, which can be handled by selecting `.annotations` class.

Here is a example:

```
const makeAnnotations = d3.annotation().annotations(annotations)

    if (year == 2009)
        {svg.append("g").call(makeAnnotations)}
    else {d3.select(".annotations").remove()}
```